# How to List Azure Network Security Group from all Subscription using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-security, azure-nsg

I am trying to create an PowerShell script to list Azure Network Security Groups and it's rule from all subscription and export it to CSV.

Below is my code which list all the NSG Rule Name,Description,Priority,SourceAddressPrefix,SourcePortRange,DestinationAddressPrefix,DestinationPortRange,Protocol,Access and Direction.

```
############# List All Azure Network Security Groups #############
$subs = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

    Foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
        $nsgRules = $nsg.SecurityRules

        foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) {
            $nsgRule | Select-Object @{n='SubscriptionName';e={$sub.Name}},
                @{n='ResourceGroupName';e={$nsg.ResourceGroupName}},
                @{n='NetworkSecurityGroupName';e={$nsg.Name}},
                Name,Description,Priority,
                @{Name='SourceAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourceAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='SourcePortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourcePortRange))}},
                @{Name='DestinationAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='DestinationPortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationPortRange))}},
                Protocol,Access,Direction |
                    Export-Csv "C:\Users\admin-vishal.singh\Desktop\Test\nsg\NsgRules.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Append        
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am Getting for above script
[image]

I also tried to call object Resourcegroup, SubscriptionName under **$nsgRule | Select-Object** it gave me blank column with header Resourcegroup, subscriptionName.

I am trying to get output like this:

[image]

I don't know at which for loop I need to do changes to get output like above.

Basically, I am trying to list all the Azure NSGs with Rules from all subscription with there respective ResourcegroupName, subscriptionName.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra properties you want to return belong to a different object than `$nsgRule`. You can still retrieve those properties through the use of `Select-Object`'s calculated properties.

```
$subs = Get-AzureRmSubscription

foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $nsgs = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup

    Foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
        $nsgRules = $nsg.SecurityRules

        foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) {
            $nsgRule | Select-Object @{n='SubscriptionName';e={$sub.Name}},
                @{n='ResourceGroupName';e={$nsg.ResourceGroupName}},
                @{n='NetworkSecurityGroupName';e={$nsg.Name}},
                Name,Description,Priority,
                @{Name='SourceAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourceAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='SourcePortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourcePortRange))}},
                @{Name='DestinationAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='DestinationPortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationPortRange))}},
                Protocol,Access,Direction |
                    Export-Csv "C:\Vishal\NsgRules.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Append        
        }
    }
}
```

`$nsg` contains `ResourceGroupName` and `Name` (the network security group name). `$sub` contains the subscription name as `Name`.

Comment: I tried this but it gives output as blank csv.

Comment: I just ran it in azure cloud shell, and it output everything. I used azure cloud storage for my output location though

Comment: I tried to run on azure cloud shell but is giving me error.
`./Azurecli-nsg.ps1 "nsg list"`  it gives error like below
**admin-vishal_singh@Azure:~/clouddrive$ ./Azurecli-nsg.ps1 "nsg list"
./Azurecli-nsg.ps1: line 2: =: command not found
./Azurecli-nsg.ps1: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./Azurecli-nsg.ps1: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$sub'
'/Azurecli-nsg.ps1: line 4: `foreach ($sub in $subs) {**

Comment: I am running the same code you posted with extra properties added to select-object. So if mine has issues, then yours should have had the same issues.

Comment: I fixed all the curly quotes that were in your original script. Maybe they are causing issues.

Comment: I think I had issue in my script with spaces, I tried to arranged code and now it worked.
Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps a bit... I'm doing similar and using the az cli (which has direct conversions to powershell)

I'm taking this approach:

```
#get all the subs in a list
$subs_list = az account list --query [].[id] -o tsv

#loop through list of subs
foreach($sub in $subs_list)
{
    az account set --subscription $sub # change the active sub
    $rg_list = az group list | ConvertFrom-json # retrieve a list of resource groups for that sub
    foreach($rg in $rg_list) # loop through the list of resource groups
    {
        $nsg_list = az network nsg list --resource-group $rg.name | ConvertFrom-json # get the list of nsg for a resource group
        foreach($nsg in $nsg_list) # loop through the list of nsg
        {
            $nsg_rules = az network nsg rule list --nsg $nsg.name --resource-group $rg.name -o table # get a list of rules for each nsg
            $nsg_rules # print the rules to screen
        }
        

    }
}
```

You'll have to figure out how to format it all, but you now have the subscription object in $sub and the resource group in $rg via $rg.name or $rg.id...

I hope that helps, I'm new to this as well and this is my first question answered on here :)

Comment: Are you mixing `az cli` with Powershell?